# Sort MongoDb documents with foreign characters using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting

I have a dataset containing a list with languages each language is written in the language presented

e.g.

- Deutsch
- Nederlands
- Slovenčina
- Česky
- Български

The problem is when I do a sort on the language I get the list as presented above. However natural would be

- Български
- Česky
- Deutsch
- Nederlands
- Slovenčina

How would you suggest to do this?

One would be creating a sorting field, but I have another collection with 15.000 documents and making a sort index on this is a lot of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB does not have locale based sorting, and instead just uses the Unicode 
codepoint ordering. This works fine for the standard English language alphabet, but obviously not for others. This issue is being tracked [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1920) and a workaround can be found [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1920?focusedCommentId=175927&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-175927)

My answer was taken from the Google Groups question posted [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/odTnyzI2PqQ/08LqkRUaFbUJ) in regards to swedish letter sorting. If you want to read more about Unicode Collation you can check out the [Unicode Technical Standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/)

A suggestion would be to pull your data into a language which handles Unicode Collation properly and apply your sort field from there. Or, commonly lists of languages will also include a Locale Code (EN for English for example), and this is what they sort.

Using the list of Locale codes then your order will be correct as per your example:

> 1. Български (Bulgarian) - BG
> 2. Česky (I am guessing Czech/Česka) - CS
> 3. Deutsch - DE
> 4. Nederlands - NL
> 5. Slovenčina - SK

Comment: I will use approach with the Locale Code, for the 15K + documents, I'll see if I'll manage to patch the database engine as described in the link you provided.

Comment: Let me know how it goes if you don't mind, I am quite interested.

Answer (score 0):

I used this configuración in finn, in this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/ you can find information about it.

```
collation : { locale: "country"}
//example query filter by "field"
db.items.find({"field": "value"}).sort({"field" : -1}).collation({"locale": "pl"})
```